# Move title above div without using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to make a element-builder (CMS) with which you can drag and drop elements into a page and easily create websites.
I am using the bootstrap templates (css,js) to get a responsive website.

The problem is the following:

```
_col-md-4_______________________
|                               |
| Page Title                    |
|_______________________________|
|           |                   |
|Image      | (main content)    |
|           |                   |
|           |                   |
|div=col-xs-2___div=col-xs-10___|
```

My title must be aligned above the main content.

I tried to create a responsive result by using Javascript:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    var witdh = $(\'.calculate-witdh\').innerWidth();
    $(".title-offset").each(function(){$(this).css(\'margin-left\', witdh)});
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
    var witdh = $(\'.calculate-witdh\').innerWidth();
    $(".title-offset").each(function(){$(this).css(\'margin-left\', witdh)});
    });
    </script>
```

But I think there has to be a better solution?
Mainly because I don't want each element to load in it's own script.

Example found here: http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/vuskazh1/

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: please give more information ...

Comment: Please show us some HTML and the relevant CSS and we'll be able to help.

Comment: JSfiddle added : http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/vuskazh1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
<h1 class="title-offset col-xs-offset-2">Create a title here</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/mhqxtppn/

Comment: Yes! Yes it does. Is this basic CSS? Is it possible you can give me a bit more information about this function? Is this Bootstrap functionality?

Comment: Yes. `offset` is a feature of the Bootstrap library that adds "virtual" columns. You can read about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).